# 'For loop' Converts Characters to Integer terminates in parenthesis pair

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am writing a Caesar Cipher in Scala 3, I am writing an expression/function that iterates through each character of a string. Upon each iteration each character is converted to a ascii value, shifted, then converted back to character. The function prints, however the output terminates in "()"     ...

```
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine  
  
var message: String = "";
var shift: Int = 1;

def encrypt(messageToDecrypt: String, shiftAmt: Int): Unit =  
  var msgLen = messageToDecrypt.length
  var dcrytArray = messageToDecrypt.toCharArray
  var i : Int = 0
  var shiftedCharArray = for i <- dcrytArray do print(((i.toInt + shiftAmt - 97) % 26 + 97).toChar)
  

@main def CeasarCipher(args: String*): Unit = 
  println("enter a phrase to encrypt: ")
  var message = readLine()
  var encryptedmessage = encrypt(message, shift)
  println(encryptedmessage)
```

Why is the output terminating with "( )"? and how can I resolve?

Comment: You've declared the return type of `encrypt` as `Unit`, so that's exactly what you're printing out. I think you want `encrypt` to actually return the encrypted value rather than to print it out and return nothing.

Comment: I've tried to return encrypt as a String by using .MkString(" ") and .toString on shiftedCharArray, but it returns  only "()"

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use vars, arrays, mutable structures, and procedural loops, it hurts my eyes :( If you are going to spend time learning scala, might as well learn using it in the right way.

```
def shift(amt: Int)(x: Char) = ((x + amt - 97)%26+97).toChar
println(encryptedMessage.map(shift(shiftAmt)))
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it, you have to use "yield" rather than "do" in the for loop

```
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine  
  
  var message: String = "";
  var shift: Int = 1;

  def encrypt(messageToDecrypt: String, shiftAmt: Int): String =  
  var msgLen = messageToDecrypt.length
  var dcrytArray = messageToDecrypt.toCharArray
  var i : Int = 1
  var shiftedCharArray = for i <- dcrytArray yield ((i.toInt + shiftAmt - 97) % 26 + 97).toChar
   shiftedCharArray.mkString("")
  

@main def CeasarCipher(args: String*): Unit = 
  println("enter a phrase to encrypt: ")
  var message = readLine()
  var encryptedmessage = encrypt(message, shift)
  println(encryptedmessage)
```

Comment: Right, `do` maps to `foreach` which doesn't return a value, whereas `yield` is translated to a `map` call that does return a value. Here's more details on how the compiler handles for comprehensions: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html